# Do smooth, homotopic curves in a manifold have a smooth variation from one to the other?

Tags: differential-geometry, homotopy-theory

The motivation for this is demonstrating that the proof in [Simply connected manifold with nonpositive curvature has no more than one geodesic between points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075860/simply-connected-manifold-with-nonpositive-curvature-has-no-more-than-one-geodes) is correct (or learning that it is false).

My argument for the statement being true is that a homotopy gives an $f:[0,1]\times[0,L]\to M$, with $f_0,f_1$ smooth. Since every point has a convex neighborhood and $[0,1]\times[0,L]$ is compact, we can take some positive $\epsilon_0$ such that $f(s+\epsilon,t)$ stays within a convex neighborhood of some maximal radius $r_0$ of $f(s,t)$ when $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$.

Then we can take $s$ in increments of $\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$ and take a homotopy of $f(k*\frac{\epsilon_0}{2},t)$ to some $\tilde{f}$ smooth in $t$ by moving to points within $\frac{r_0}{3}$, thus staying within the convex neighborhoods of the original points. Thus we can bridge the gap between increments of $s$ by the exponential map of something smooth in $s$ from $\tilde{f}(k*\frac{\epsilon_0}{2},t)$ to $\tilde{f}((k+1)*\frac{\epsilon_0}{2},t)$, giving a smooth variation from $f_0$ to $f_1$. The vectors can be chosen to match on both sides of each increment, so that the smoothness continues across each increment of $s$.

Comment: What is your "something smooth " ? I would look at the convolution $\psi_\epsilon \ast (\varphi \circ f )$ with $\varphi$ a chart, $\psi_\epsilon \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $f$ made constant outside of $(0,1)\times (0,L)$. Then it is a matter of a smooth transition from $f_0$ to $\varphi \circ f_0$ using a $C^\infty$ approximation of $\frac{1+sign(k)}{2}$

Comment: @reuns The 'something smooth' was meant to be choosing smooth vector fields such that the exponentiation of those vector fields has derivatives that match on either side of the fixed points in $s$. Using coordinate charts did not occur to me, but looks to simplify the problem. However, if you happen to know that the statement is true or not, I would appreciate you explicitly telling me - I've been trying to prove the motivating statement for weeks (with a wildly incorrect proof given in December) and the exam is tomorrow.